# How to use const keyword (ecma 6) with function static variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript function which has a static variable:

```
function Constants() {

}

Constants.i = '1';
```

Now according to ECMA 6 we have const keyword. Using this we can make a variable as immutable.

I am not able to find how to use const keyword with function static variable, if I use like below it is not loading the function:

```
const Constant.i = '1';
```

It will be very helpful if anyone can suggest the proper way of doing the same.

Comment: There are no static variables in JavaScript. What you have is a *property*. There are ways to make it non-writable, but not using a keyword or declaration like `const`.

Comment: `const Constant.i = '1';` it will raise an error. Probably it will help you [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: `const` is not making a variable immutable, it just makes sure the reference to the value won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` only works for variables, not for object (or function) properties.

As mentioned above, you can use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define an object property that cannot be changed:

```
function Constants() {

}

Object.defineProperty(Constants, 'i', {
    value: '1',
    writable: false, // this prevents the property from being changed
    enumerable: true, // this way, it shows up if you loop through the properties of Constants
    configurable: false // this prevents the property from being deleted
});
```